# JPA object mapping doesn't save children on insert

Tags: oracle, jpa, playframework

I´ve got this Model on my Play application.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SHOPPER")
public class User extends GenericModel {

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SASHNBR", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public List<Direction> directions;
}
```

The Direction Model looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SHADDR")
public class Direccion extends GenericModel {

    ...

    @Column(name="SASHNBR")
    @Required
    public Long idUser;
}
```

This way I´ve got an error because Direction doens't have the idUser generated when saving.

I´ve tried this way too.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SHOPPER")
public class User extends GenericModel {

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    public List<Direction> directions;
}
```

The Direction Model looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SHADDR")
public class Direccion extends GenericModel {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SASHNBR", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    User user;
}
```

But it didn't work either.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: the correct JPA way is the one you described in your 2nd approach. How are you trying to persist the object? How are you creating the object? Are there any error messages or is it only the case that user gets persisted, but not the directions?

Comment: The error is that I can't save the children because I dont have the parent id on Directions. It´s like the foreing key mapping its not working. Even in the second aproach. I´m persisting it with .save().

Comment: You don't neeed the parent's id. This will be taken care of by JPA. All you want to do is to make sure that for all your Direction instances in the directions list you have set the user they belong to

Comment: Yup, I know JPA will propagate it on its own, but it doesn't :S :P. When it gets to the child and goes to save it, breaks and doesn't even save the parent. ORA-01400: cannot make a NULL insert on ("SHADDR"."SASHNBR")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to save the children your self. You can look at the [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/guide2) for an example.

```
public User addDirection(Direction direction) {    
    this.directions.add(direction);
    this.save();
    return this;
}

@Override
public User save(){
    for (Direction dir : directions) {
        dir.save()
    }
    super.save()
    return this;
}
```

Comment: I´ve tried it before, and it works that way. But there´s not a way to save the object user and get it´s children saved to whith the parent id propagated by JPA? I just want to do user.save() and get Directions saved too. Thanks :)

Comment: Then you could override the user save() method, iterate through directions and save each one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the aproach but I think there may be a way to do it without iterating the child. If I can't make it work I´ll go with this one. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like this:

```
User user = new User();
// [...] call required setters of user object
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    Direction direction = new Direction();
    direction.setUser(user);
    // [...] call other required setters of direction object
    user.getDirections().add(direction);
}
entitymanager.persist(user);
```

Comment: I´ve tried it before, and it works that way. But there´s not a way to save the object user and get it´s children saved to whith the parent id propagated by JPA? I just want to do user.save() and get Directions saved too. Thanks :)

Comment: you are only saving the user (entitymanager.persist)... it all depends how and where you are adding the directions. You could have all the steps I have in the for loop in a method "addDirection" in the User object and then on a save you would only have to call persist for the user.
e.g. in the User class:
void addDirection(Direction direction) {
    direction.setUser(this);    
    directions.add(direction);
}

Comment: Have to try this one, will comment when done. Thanks for all @Korgen